# Horizontal scrolling to navigate between the windows of application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create an application with two or three screens for pc with tactile screen by using c# and WPF.

I would like to be able to navigate through the windows of my application by sliding the finger across the screen (left to right for previous screen or right to left for next screen).

How to proceed with c# and wpf ? What are the controls to use ? MatrixTransform and Manipulation events ? Scrollviewer ?

How to make the different windows of the application attached while gliding ? I mean: for right to left slide operation, we begin to see the next window while the current window disappears step by step.

Comment: I'd like to confirm what you mean by 'window'? Do you have a multi window application or rather many controls embedded within a single window?

Comment: I've a multi window application because each window gives me another data context. For example: first window for main data of the application, second window for logs display, ...

Comment: What if for example 10 windows are opened and a user randomly arranged them? Should they be re-arrange while sliding?

Comment: There will be only two or three windows and each window keeps its fix relative position. If the user wants to have a regard to the second window, he glides his finger from right to left. The user cannot rearrange them.

Answer (score 0):

My answer takes into account your additional comments, especially this one "*There will be only two or three windows and each window keeps its **fix relative position.***". It suggests that you actually don't need windows. It'll be sufficient and much more easier to use custom user controls. These controls should placed next to each other. You can achieve it by using *StackPanel* with the horizontal orientation. This *StackPanel* should be inside *ScrollViever* which will provide scrolling. Additionally, *ScrollViewer* has *[PanningMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode(v=vs.110).aspx)* property which controls how it will cooperate with touch screens. Here is an example showing an idea:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Height="600" 
        Width="800">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <UserControl Width="500" Height="500" Background="Red" />
            <UserControl Width="500" Height="500" Background="Blue" />
            <UserControl Width="500" Height="500" Background="Yellow" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ok, use the ScrollViewer like I suggested in my question, but how to block the scroll on a window with the ScrollViewer when the move performed by the user has been enough efficient (sort of magnetic effect) ?

Comment: You wrote about ScrollViewer in your question, but you wouldn't use it with  independent windows. What do you mean by "enough efficient"?

Comment: The context of my windows is different. So, my windows are independent. "enough efficient" means: when the previous/next window area appears for more than 80% (for example) or when the current window area disappears for more 80%. I don't know if it exists adapted controls for that. What do I have to use ? Do I have to work with the Manipulation events of the ScrollViewer or does it exist another way ?

Comment: Custom user controls can also have different contexts and be independent from each other. Your requirements seems to be very specific and I don't know a container of the shelf that can do it. I think that you will have to implement it on your own, either by using Touch events or Manipulation API (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx).

Comment: What I want to do is a FlipView control without the left and right arrows in WPF and C# and in which I could add my windows.